# get site type through sharepoint 2007 web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to dig out what the type of a site is through web services in Sharepoint 2007.  If it's a team site, meeting site, or so on.  I've been digging through the documentation on the web services and I don't see how to do this... does anyone know where it's at?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one ever responded to this, the only way I was able to get what I wanted for this was to check for a particular site template was there...  I was trying to determine if it was a meeting site or not, and by checking the site templates, I could determine if it was a team site or a meeting site.